# Sending text from iPhone to Windows PC via bluetooth

Tags: ios, windows, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

How to send data from an iPhone app to Windows app (or service) in real-time? Ideally over Bluetooth.

Basically as I type on my iPhone app, I want that text to appear on my Windows App (with-in a second or less).

How can I go about achieving this? I'd imagine there is some center-peripheral setup I need to establish. What are the libraries to use on both sides? Have never worked with Bluetooth in the past, so kinda lost. I looked into Apple's `Multi peer Connectivity` but that looks like iOS-Mac specific.

Comment: Not sure how to do it with Bluetooth but fairly easy with WiFi by using BSD socket.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I cannot use WiFi

Comment: via Bluetooth is much more complicated than via Internet / local network. Must use Bluetooth?

Comment: @Raptor yes unfortunately. Although I’m curious why you think internet/local network will be easier than Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea on the Windows side, on iOS you would use Core Bluetooth to configure the app as either a peripheral or a central.